# How get size between tableView and tabBar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have dynamic `UITableView`. When rows don't enough to fill screen, I am going programmatically draw `UIView` and set it to `self.tableView.tableFooterView`. Empty row has image (red line).
I need to know size x (see image) for know how much rows need to draw. How can I get it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get contentSize and do a difference from table view's frame size. So for example:

```
let space = tableView.frame.height - tableView.contentSize.height
```

And if there is more content than the tableView height (if it scrolls) this value will be negative, and in that case just replace it with 0.

Also for this to work you already have to add cells and call `reloadData()`.

Other option would be to multiply the number of rows by `tableView.rowHeight` (if it's fixed), or call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for each row and add it all together.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGSize statusBarSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size;
    CGSize navigationBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size;
    CGSize tableViewContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
    CGSize tabBarSize = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size;

    UIView *tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tableViewContentSize.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - statusBarSize.height - navigationBarSize.height - tableViewContentSize.height - tabBarSize.height)];
    tableFooterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = tableFooterView;
}
```