# How to know tableView.contentSize before viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I say before ([How get size between tableView and tabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899435/how-get-size-between-tableview-and-tabbar)) that going to programmatically draw cell.

For to know, how much cell to draw, I need tableView.contentSize.height, how to get it before viewDidAppear(), in viewWillAppear() I get not relevant size.
If I draw in viewDidAppear() it is visibly for user, how Image is Appear.

Comment: are you want to get the contentSize of UITableView But with load of data into  UITableView it's not possible.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayname.count
}

Comment: can u show the code u used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your cells have the same size, then the tableView.contentSize will be nr of cells X cell height.